# Alternative to XSLT?

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, xslt

on my project I have a huuuuge XSLT used to convert some XML files to HTML.
The problem is that this file is growing up day by day, it's hard to read, debug and test.
So I was thinking about moving all the parsing process to Java.

Do you think is a good idea? In case what libraries to parse XML and generate HTML(XML) do u suggest? performances will be better or worse?

If it's not a good idea any alternative idea?

Thanks

Randomize

Comment: There is a chance that the XSLT can be simplified, depending on how it is implemented. Could you explain why the file grows by each day and maybe post an example of the code?

Comment: I'm not exactly an XSLT expert and sometimes there are some requests by the customer about picking data up and down from the XML to create nested structure like list of list of list of data, and doing it with XSLT is not exactly what I mean for easy. Maybe I could think about a mix of Java and XSLT?

Comment: There are many ways to get XSLT wrong, and then it suddenly seems *a lot* harder and clumsier than it actually is. I suppose there is room for improvement in your code, if you want to try that first.

Comment: XSLT has good features for modular programming. Split your code into different stylesheet modules and use `<xsl:import>` or `<xsl:include>` to use them in your main stylesheet module. The fact that you have allowed the code to become "huuuuge" is indicative only of your abilities as a programmer, not of any design flaws in XSLT.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider [Velocity](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-velocity) as an alternative.  I prefer it to XSL-T.  The transforms are harder to write than templates, because the latter look exactly like the XML I wish to produce.  It's a simple thing to add in the markup to map in the data.

Comment: we use Velocity in our project, but the parsing is executed by XSLT. Can you show me please a simple example about what you mean? Thanks

Comment: No, XSL-T isn't a parser.  It's for transforming XML from one form to another.  SAX or DOM are examples of parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CDuce](http://www.cduce.org/) - it is a strictly typed, statically compiled XML processing language.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a client with a similar problem - thousands of lines of XSLT, growing all the time. I spent an hour reading it with increasing incredulity, then rewrote it in 20 lines of XSLT.

Refactoring is often a good idea, and the worse the code is, the more worthwhile refactoring is. But there's no reason to believe that just because the code is bad and in need of refactoring, you need to change to a different programming language. XST is actually very good at handling variety and complexity if you know how to use it properly.

It's possible that the code is an accumulation of special handling of special cases, and each new special case discovered results in more rules being added. That's a tough problem to tackle in any language, but XSLT can deal with it better than most, provided you apply your mind all the time to finding abstract general rules that encompass all the special rules, so you only need to code the special rules as exceptions.